# Is it always safe to change a C-style cast to a static_cast?

Tags: c++, static-cast

I am trying to eliminate all C-style casts in a codebase, due to cppcheck cstyleCast style warnings.

**Is it always safe to change a C-style cast to a `static_cast`?**

By safe, I mean, is there a situation where the old C-style cast would work fine, but `static_cast` would raise error or undefined behavior?

```
type1 a;
type2 b = (type2)a;               // C style cast
type2 b = static_cast<type2>(a);  // Is this always a valid replacement for above cast?
```

Comment: C cast might be a `const_cast`, but you will have a compile time error with `static_cast` in that case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C-style cast is generally a combo of `static_cast<>` or `reinterpret_cast<>` with `const_cast<>`. There might be compile-time errors from replacing it with just `static_cast<>`.

I am not aware of any cases for runtime errors.

You could start with `static_cast<>`, then add (or replace it with) `const_cast<>` where compile-time errors arise. If after that you still have compile-time errors, `reinterpret_cast<>` are required. But do not make the replacement blindly - some of these cases may be bugs. E.g., `reinterpret_cast<>` may be required if a data type is forward declared but not defined, which leads to unspecified behavior (and will definitely cause  problems if multiple inheritance is involved).

Finding these kinds of bugs is the reason why this exercise improves safety of the source code, and why a static code analyzer flags C-style casts.

Answer (score 2):

C- style cast and `static_cast` are not equivalent.

> is there a situation where the old C-style cast would work fine, but static_cast would raise error or undefined behavior?

As an example:

```
int main() {
    using FI = int(*)();
    using FV = void(*)();
    FI fi = nullptr;
    FV fv = (FV)fi;
    //FV fv2 = static_cast<FV>(fi);
}
```

If you uncomment the line that uses `static_cast`, the code doesn't compile.
As a side note, in this case you should rather use `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: If the code does not compile. Then it is safe (as you have no bugs introduced into your code). You are conflating safe and valid which are different concepts.

Comment: @LokiAstari Not exactly. OP asked for a case in which a `static_cast` would raise an error and a C-style cast would work (quoted). In the answer there is such a case. I didn't say it's valid or safe, I posted only an example that reflects what the OP is asking for. That's all. Honestly I didn't get what he means with safe. An UB would be unsafe probably, but an error is safe enough, you can correct it before to release anything.